# Adding class to the comment form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

I want to add a class to the form, not form items. I've looked on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form but there is no mention of adding a class to the form.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**:

Wordpress finally supports the possibility to add classes to the comments form. See [Nabil Kadimi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828166/1278475) to get an example.

---

***My outdated answer***:

Because Wordpress still hasn't supported this option, I've worked out the following workaround:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    comment_form();
    echo str_replace('class="comment-form"','class="comment-form your-custom-class"',ob_get_clean());
?>
```

Now the standard class `comment-form` will be replaced by itself plus the custom class.

Comment: This is so simple, but it's absolutely brilliant.

Comment: Can we replace multiple classes ? How?

Comment: Hi @Nigel, I would suggest you the approach using hooks as [mentioned by Nabil Kadimi in her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36828166/1278475). This would overwrite all defined classes for the comments form.

Answer (score 7):

In the [documentation for the `comment_form()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/):

> WordPress 4.4.0   Introduced the **'class_form'** [...] arguments.

So you would do:

```
// Output the comment form with a custom class:
comment_form ( array( 'class_form' => 'my_custom_class' ) );
```

---

#### One a second thought

I prefer using hooks:

```
/**
 * Callback function for the `comment_form_defaults` filter hook
 *
 * @param Array $defaults Defaults.
 * @return Array          Defaults modified.
 */
function se_8476425_modify_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
    $defaults[ 'class_form' ] = 'class1 class2 class3';
    return $defaults;
};

add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'se_8476425_modify_comment_form_defaults' );
```

This solution is more generic as you can use it to modify the default function behavior and themes you don't "own".

Comment: any ideas on how to add class to the comment wrapper with id="respond"?

Comment: @raison It's not practical to ask questions on comment. Kindly ask a new question using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 3):

Since wordpress versión 4.1 (Dec, 2014) the comment_form function allows to specify a class attribute for the submit button.

Php Code:

```
$comments_args = array('class_submit' => 'btn btn-default');
comment_form($comments_args);
```

Resultant HTML Button code:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
```

For reference see the related ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20446

Answer (score 2):

You can easily modify the code of the submit button of the coment form with this filter :

```
function custom_submit_comment_form( $submit_button ) {
  return '<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn_2" value="Laisser un commentaire" />';
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_submit_button', 'custom_submit_comment_form' );
```

Answer (score -3):

You can just edit your single.php and wrap the :

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

In a class. Something like:

```
<div class="myClass">
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</div>
```